# Android and UWB

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, pixel, uwb

Hey fellow Android devs!  I'm diving into Android development and UWB technology. I've got this idea of creating an app that shows an arrow pointing towards another device's direction, like a digital compass. I'm wondering, what kind of values can I use to figure out the angle? Do I need to consider things like elevation and azimuth?

Speaking of azimuth, I already tried connecting my two Pixel 7 Pros thru BLE as OOB, and Android UWB API give values in the -90 to 90 range. How can I work around that to get a complete 360-degree direction? Any advice or insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code where you use the "Android UWB API". I'm confused when you use UWB and BLE in the same sentence, I always thought they are different. Also have you checked the android example on uwb? https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/main/UwbRanging